# How to read an image inside a zip file with PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, zip, python-imaging-library

Can I open an image inside a zip with PIL/Pillow without extracting it to disk first?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The recent Pillow releases do not require `.seek()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from zipfile import ZipFile
from PIL import Image # $ pip install pillow

filename = sys.argv[1]
with ZipFile(filename) as archive:
    for entry in archive.infolist():
        with archive.open(entry) as file:
            img = Image.open(file)
            print(img.size, img.mode, len(img.getdata()))
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know since which version of Pillow?

Comment: @TorKlingberg: it fails on 2.7. It works on 2.9+. You could try to find a specific issue on github.

Comment: The current [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) for Image.open still says "The file object must implement read(), seek(), and tell() methods"

Comment: @TorKlingberg: "must" is probably a bug in the docs. Here're [release notes for 2.8 that explicitly says that Image wraps the non-seekable files itself](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/2.8.0.html)

Comment: That's good. Ubuntu 14.04 only has Pillow 2.3.0. I will look into setting up a virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

Pythons [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) does provide a `ZipFile.open()` that returns a file object for a file inside the zip, and [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html)'s `Image.open()` can take file object to open from. Unfortunately the zipfile object does not provide the `seek()` method that `Image.open()` needs.

Instead read the image file into a string in RAM (if it is not too big), and use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to get a file object for `Image.open()`:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

archive = ZipFile("file.zip", 'r')
image_data = archive.read("image.png")
fh = StringIO(image_data)
img = Image.open(fh)
```

Comment: It may be better to use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead of `StringIO`, though both seem to work in this case.

Comment: StringIO did not work on my machine... "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes", no pb using BytesIO